# How to rename a partitions table with child tables

Tags: mysql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I am trying to rename parent table in partitions. I created 3 child tables on year wise manner. I can alter the name of parent table but I don't know how to alter the 3 child table references.

This is my structure of partition tables.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_demos(
id bigserial NOT NULL,  
partition_by integer NOT NULL,
names character varying (80) NOT NULL,
age integer,
aed character varying (5) NOT NULL,
entered_user_id integer,
entered_post_id integer,
entered_office_id integer,
dept_code character varying (25) NOT NULL,
owner_dept_code character varying (25) NOT NULL,
approval character varying (5) NOT NULL,
which inet,
whom macaddr,
who character varying(50),
row_created_at timestamp(0) WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL DEFAULT 
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
PARTITION BY LIST(partition_by);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_demos2019s PARTITION OF test_demos FOR VALUES IN (2019);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_demos2020s PARTITION OF test_demos FOR VALUES IN (2020);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_demos2021s PARTITION OF test_demos FOR VALUES IN (2021);
```

Comment: What do you want to alter in the child tables?

Comment: i also want to change child tables names

Comment: Provided you the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PostgreSQL this works, as I think, like this.

```sql
ALTER TABLE test_demos2019s RENAME TO new_table_name;
ALTER TABLE test_demos2020s RENAME TO new_table_name2;
ALTER TABLE test_demos2021s RENAME TO new_table_name3;
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can crete a function, which can rename all child partitions using some pattern

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION rename_partitions(oldname VARCHAR, newname VARCHAR)
   RETURNS VOID AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
   table_rec RECORD;
BEGIN
   FOR table_rec IN
      SELECT  inhrelid::REGCLASS::TEXT AS old_tblname, 
              REPLACE(inhrelid::REGCLASS::TEXT, oldname, newname) AS new_tblname
      FROM   pg_catalog.pg_inherits
      WHERE  inhparent = newname::REGCLASS
   LOOP
      EXECUTE FORMAT($$ALTER TABLE %I RENAME TO %I$$, 
              table_rec.old_tblname, table_rec.new_tblname);
   END LOOP;
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

More information is available here:

- [Object Identifier Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-oid.html)
- [Alter Table command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-altertable.html)
- [String Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-string.html)
- [pg_inherits](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/catalog-pg-inherits.html)

Answer (score 0):

The syntax to change the table name is,

```
alter table table_name to new_table_name;
```

In your case it's:

```
alter table test_demos2019s to new_table_name;
alter table test_demos2020s to new_table_name;
alter table test_demos2021s to new_table_name;
```